# CollectionView crash after delete item

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that scrolls horizontally inside a UITableViewCell(attached screenshot). In collectionView, the first cell to add more item, beside is clubs list.

```
//MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return 1 + arrClubs.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellAdd, for: indexPath) as! FXFiltersAddCollectionViewCell
        
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellTeam, for: indexPath) as! FXFiltersTeamCollectionViewCell
        
        let isValidIndex = arrClubs.indices.contains(indexPath.item-1)
        if isValidIndex == true {
            let clubMO = Utils.clubFromId(clubId: arrClubs[indexPath.item-1])
            
            cell.lbName.text = clubMO?.short_name
            cell.imgLogo.setImage(url: clubMO?.icon, placeholder: nil)
        }
        
        cell.delegate = self
        
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

Now, I delete each cell by press "x" button.

```
func didSelectRemoveClub(cell: FXFiltersTeamCollectionViewCell) {
    if let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) {
        self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            let isValidIndex = arrClubs.indices.contains(indexPath.item-1)
            if isValidIndex == true {
                arrClubs.remove(at: (indexPath.item - 1))
                
                self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
            }
        }, completion: { (finished) in

        })
    }
}
```

Suppose, I have 6 clubs cell, I delete 1st, 2nd, 3rd club cell, it works fine. Then I delete 4th cell, it crashes:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'

But if before delete, I scroll collectionView to the last cell and comeback first cell, it works fine!

[image]

Comment: is this App Crashing when you try to delete the Very first Item ?

Comment: Suppose, I have 6 clubs cell, I delete 1st, 2nd, 3rd club cell, it work fine. Then I delete 4th cell, it crash

Comment: @TàTruhoada Use this github -> https://github.com/thedahiyaboy/TDTagIndex

Comment: @dahiya_boy: thanks! I will try it

Comment: Did you try reloading the collectionview after deletion? Try reloading it in the completion block

Comment: did you checked the indexPath returned from self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) ?

Comment: this is happened because indexpath is not updated. after delete try to reload all collectionview @TàTruhoada

Comment: @Vinaykrishnan Yes, I did try it, but still crash

Comment: @Hitesh I also think so, and I did try reload collectionview, but not working, then I did try auto scroll to last cell and scroll back, sometimes it works, sometimes it crashes.

Comment: if arrClubs contain any unique key, find from arrClubs and remove that object and try to reload collectionview @TàTruhoada

Answer (score 1):

try below update delete collection cell before delete object from array:

```
func didSelectRemoveClub(cell: FXFiltersTeamCollectionViewCell) {
    if let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) {
        self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            let isValidIndex = arrClubs.indices.contains(indexPath.item)
            if isValidIndex == true {

                self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
                arrClubs.remove(at: (indexPath.item))
            }
        }, completion: { (finished) in

        })
    }
}
```

Comment: data update needs to happen before the collection view. This will cause a guaranteed crash.

Comment: I tested it and No crashed happened

Comment: I did try this before, but it still crash :(